# Prove that $\sup_A f = \sup f|_{\mathbb Q\cap A} = \sup f |_{(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})\cap A}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

I was trying to prove something else and this came up. It must be really simple to prove but I am struggling to do it. Let $A$ be a non-empty and compact interval of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f \colon A \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous fuction. Then:

$$
\sup_A f = \sup f|_{\mathbb Q\cap A} = \sup f |_{(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})\cap A}
$$

Any ideas on how can I prove it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: What will happen if those supremums (suprema?) are not equal? Can you see that by 'drawing' a graph, and then try to write a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for one proof: replace $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ by any dense set $B$ and prove $\sup f|_A \leq \sup f|_B$ (or if you prefer: that it's impossiblle to have $\sup f|_A > \sup f|_B$ ).

Hint for another proof: prove that the image of a dense subset is dense in the image.

Hint for another proof: a continuous function is semi-continuous (both upper-and lower); read about the topological definition of upper/lower semicontinuity; everything should follow abstractly.

Hint for another proof: Let $Y$ be the set of strict upper bounds: these are numbers $y$ such that there exist positive $z$ such that for all $x$ we have $f(x)+z<y$.
Prove that the set of upper bounds if the same, if $x$ is restricted to a dense subset

Comment: I proved that $Im(A \cap \mathbb{Q})$ is dense in $Im(A)$. However I don't know how to use that to prove that statement. I mean, since $Im(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})$ is also dense in $Im(A)$ this leaves me with a finite union of unity sets, which I can not use to prove the first statement.

Comment: Great, you did almost everything! I'll guide you to the end now: what is "sup f"? It is just the upper limit of the set "Im(f)". 

But if a set is dense into another, then they have the same upper limit! (if you prefer: their closure is the same, so all the limit points are the same, so in particular the maximal one is the same)

Answer (score 0):

Note that in general, $\sup(B) = \max(\overline{B})$. Using continuity of $f$ and density of the rationals and irrationals, you can show that $\overline{f(A \cap \mathbb{Q})} = \overline{f(A \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}))} = f(A)$. Since their closures are equal, their supremums are equal.